# Disable HTML minification not JavaScript or CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am facing UI related issues due to my HTML is being minified. New lines are being removed. I am working in ASP.NET from around 2 years. I hadn't faced any such issue before. This is a new project so may be there is something new in newer version (MVC 5) which is causing this.

I have following HTML

```
<p style="white-space:pre-line">
    <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i> <span style="font-weight:bold">Address Work</span>
    House Number and Street
    Colony
    City
    State ZIP
</p>
```

You can see if I remove new lines from HTML it will change the appearance. Everything will be displayed in one line because I have applied `white-space:pre-line`. New lines are important to me here.

HTML is not minified in development server (localhost). It is getting minified in production server (build using Publishing).

And the interesting thing is when I do a hard-refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>). The server will not minify HTML. In case of normal F5 refresh, or in redirecting, HTML will be minified. How did server get to know that I am requesting content with a hard refresh? and Why it serves different HTML for such requests?

How can I disable HTML minification when I am not in debug mode on production server?

Answer (score 0):

You write in paragraph (`<p>` tag) so it shows what its written there, the simplest solution is to write `<br>` to break each line.

```
<p style="white-space:pre-line">
    <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i> <span style="font-weight:bold">Address Work</span><br>
   House Number and Street<br>
   Colony<br>
   City<br>
   State ZIP 
</p>
```

Comment: Actually the content of this paragraph is coming from the database. Well this is just one scenario. I am many other UI related issue due to HTML minification. I need to put this thing off. I have gzip enabled. That's enough.

Comment: cant you replace char(13) to <br> ? i know how to disable scripts minification but about disabling html minification no idea, should be some settings in web server